# Magento 2 Catalog > Products loading forever, only happens to my personal laptop device

Tags: admin

I am working with magento editor

One night there is an issue which require me to check one of the product detail in magento admin panel

I try to go into the product, one time its okay, then the next time I am unable to, when I ask my other colleagues he is able to view the catalog edit page

I even restarted my device and using other different boot method ( i have dual boot which is windows 10 and linux )

I has disabled all google chrome extension, and also try different browser

But still the catalog edit page takes forever to load,

I am thinking that Adobe might be blacklisted my device from being able to access the catalog edit page section

Only when I try acess the admin panel from my Mobile Device its okay

Hopefully there is anyone that can give me insights on what is happening and how can I make the catalog edit page accessable again from device ( now it its taking forever too load )

What I have tried and still not working

- Restart laptop to different boot OS ( Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04 )
- Disable all extension in google chrome
- Clear cache, cookies
- Using Guest Mode
- Using Private browser mode
- Using Mozila Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the product_listing entry in the **ui_bookmark** table for your user. Perhaps there's filters in place for your user that are leading to an error

Comment: Thank you, will do this once I encountered this issue again –

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced same Issue In my local m2 store.

The reason was "I've entered very long string In the search box at catalogue > product page In admin".

For the solution, I truncated the '**ui_bookmark**' table from my database. And the error was solved!

You can try this too...

Comment: Thank you, will do this once I encountered this issue again